# Why does Firefox render resized images so badly?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Here is an example of a resized image showing the comparison between the original picture, the resized picture in Firefox, and the resized picture in Chrome:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjjrB.png]

Chrome seems to render the image fine, but the image in Firefox seems very pixelated.

This is my CSS:

```
img {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 500px;
}
```

Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: you say firefox.. you should see IE, it's even worse :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image scaling causes poor quality in firefox/internet explorer but not chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945363/image-scaling-causes-poor-quality-in-firefox-internet-explorer-but-not-chrome)

Comment: have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: what image format is it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a configuration issue with the browser itself

Referencing:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/965904